# Why this example may not exit?

Tags: go, memory

This is an example from Go doc for ["The Go Memory Model"](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_10)

Code:

```
var a string
var done bool

func setup() {
    a = "hello, world"
    done = true
}

func main() {
    go setup()
    for !done {
    }
    print(a)
}
```

The origin sentence from the doc:

*As before, there is no guarantee that, in main, observing the write to done implies observing the write to a, so this program could print an empty string too. Worse, there is no guarantee that the write to done will ever be observed by main, since there are no synchronization events between the two threads. The loop in main is not guaranteed to finish.*

**Why?**

I guess the main goroutine just cache *done=false* variable in register and no any sync action to flush the register cache.

Thanks.

---

Edit 2019-08-16

I figure it out.

If `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)` is set, the only thread will always run `for !done{}`. No any chance for scheduler to switch thread context to `setup()` subgoroutine. So compiler cannot promise this example to finish.

When we call build-in lib function, runtime lib will will get chance to dispatch goroutine. eg:

```
mutex.Lock()
// 1、enter go build-in lib
// 2、switch to other goroutine if sync condition is not satisfied
// 3、condition is satisfied
someAction()
mutex.Unlock()
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a data race. The results are undefined.

```
$ go run -race racer.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00000052b581 by goroutine 6:
  main.setup()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:8 +0x70

Previous read at 0x00000052b581 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:13 +0x56

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:12 +0x46
==================
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x000000510220 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:15 +0x74

Previous write at 0x000000510220 by goroutine 6:
  main.setup()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:7 +0x3e

Goroutine 6 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:12 +0x46
==================
hello, worldFound 2 data race(s)
exit status 66
$
```

`racer.go`:

```
package main

var a string
var done bool

func setup() {
    a = "hello, world"
    done = true
}

func main() {
    go setup()
    for !done {
    }
    print(a)
}
```

`done = true` and `!done` without synchronization is a data race.

`a = "hello, world"` and `print(a)` without synchronization is a data race.

---

[Go: Data Race Detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html)

Comment: But how this data race occurs?

Comment: @meshkati: Follow the link to the data race detector. It explains data races. The output in my answer pinponts the lines where data race occurs.  Obviously, `done = true` and `!done` without  synchronization is a data race.